# insert element into list, move pre-existing elements

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a defined function (without list/string methods):
so far i have code to update at the given location, but I'm struggling to create code that can insert the variable at list location, and move existing elements over. I want the output to be ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] instead of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'].

**Please note:** this is for study, I do want to learn I'd prefer to be pointed in the right direction, not just provided the answer.

```
def insert(list1, var, i):
    counter = 0
    for i in my_list:
        if counter == i:
            my_list[i] = var
        counter += 1
    return list1

list = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
func = insert(list, 'c', 2)
```

i've been working on code overnight (sorry for such a late reply i was on a plane)

I've come up with this code and I think it works, even though it's a little crude. can anyone give some input as to whether they see this being an issue or not?

```
def insert(list1, var, i):
    new_list = []
    counter = -1
    for index in (list1[:-1]):
        counter += 1
        new_list.append(index)
        if counter == (i-1):
            new_list.append(var)

    return new_list

list2= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h']
func = insert(list2, 'g', 6)
print(func)
```

Comment: Are you not even allowed to use `list.append`? You're going to have an interesting time as I take it list-comp's haven't been taught yet? (I'd imagine that only `list.insert` is out of bounds)?

Comment: You will need to copy the list -- but since you just want a pointer to tutorial material, may I suggest http://www.effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the list to be `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`? Or do you require constant length?

Comment: it requires consistent length. the list length can not increase. append can be used

Comment: the aim of the function is to insert at a given location, and move all objects "1 to the right" but not increase the list size. my understanding of this, is that they want the end of the list to 'drop off'. it states to move all elements down, but not increase the size of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using slicing, it's fairly easy to do this without use of any `list` methods at all. If you're using Python 3.5+ with [additional unpacking generalizations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), it even looks pretty:

```
def insert(list1, var, i):
    # Reassign all elements at and beyond the insertion point to be the new
    # value, and all but the last value previously there (so size is unchanged)
    list1[i:] = var, *list1[i:-1]
```

or if mutating the caller's argument in place is bad, and you want to return a new value:

```
def insert(list1, var, i):
    # Unpacking the components sliced as before to a brand new list
    return [*list1[:i], var, *list1[i:-1]]
```

Without the unpacking generalizations, it's not quite as pretty, but still doable, either the argument mutating:

```
def insert(list1, var, i):
    # Uglier without unpacking generalizations
    list1[i], list1[i+1:] = var, list1[i:-1]
```

or new `list` constructing:

```
def insert(list1, var, i):
    # An extra temporary without unpacking generalizations, but not ugly
    return list1[:i] + [var] + list1[i:-1]
```

If you can slice or index, this won't help, but I wanted to point out the power of slice assignment and the new unpacking generalizations.

If you want a solution using only `range` and/or `.append` with no slicing:

```
def insert(list1, var, i):
    for idx in range(len(list1)-1, i, -1):
        list1[idx] = list1[idx-1]
    list1[i] = var
```

or non-mutating:

```
def insert(list1, var, i):
    newlist = []
    for idx in range(i):
        newlist.append(list1[idx])
    newlist.append(var)
    for idx in range(i, len(list1)-1):
        newlist.append(list1[idx])
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def insert(list1, var, i):
    new_list = list1[:i]
    new_list.append(var)
    new_list.extend(list1[i:])
    return new_list

list = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
func = insert(list, 'c', 2)
```

take the part of list1 up to i.  This is called slicing
tack var onto new_list with append
tack on the rest of the list with extend

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: we're not able to utilise .extend as it's a list method, the only list method available to us is .append, and the only in-built function that can also be utilised is range(). this is why i've been stuck so far.